# How to implement a SQL like container in C++

Tags: c++11, boost

Can you pls give me a tip, is there a simple way , using standard stl or boost containers, to emulate a SQL table structure with the ability to sort it by multiple columns (and maybe having clustered indices)? For example, something to hold a given table, sorted by Type, Color, Weight:

```
ID  Type    Color   Weight  Hex
1   1       NB      3.5     12
2   1       NB      3.5     14
3   1       NB      3.8     03
4   1       PP      4.0     10
5   2       DP      3.5     15
6   2       O       5.0     12
7   2       O       6.0     09
```

Thank you

Comment: First you need some kind of *structure* for each row. Then you could use some [*container*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) for the rows. Start with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use Boost MultiIndex containers. Let me draw up a sample:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f4dae9af14b9c23)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <vector>

enum class color_t { NB, PP, DP, O };

struct Record {
    int     ID;
    int     Type;
    color_t Color;
    double  Weight;
    uint8_t Hex;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using Table = boost::multi_index_container<
    Record,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::sequenced<bmi::tag<struct byInsertion> >,
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct byID>, bmi::member<Record, int, &Record::ID> >,
        bmi::hashed_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct byType>, bmi::member<Record, int, &Record::Type> >,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct byDetails>,
            bmi::composite_key<Record,
                bmi::member<Record, color_t, &Record::Color>,
                bmi::member<Record, uint8_t, &Record::Hex>,
                bmi::member<Record, double,  &Record::Weight>
            >
        >,
        bmi::random_access<bmi::tag<struct byCustomRandomAccess> >
    >
>;

#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>  // lazy demo purposes
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp> 
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext.hpp> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::adaptors;


int main() {
    auto getId = [](auto& r) { return r.ID; };

    auto dump = [](auto&& range) -> auto& { 
        for (auto&& v:range) std::cout << v << " ";
        return std::cout;
    };

    Table table {
       Record { 4, 1, color_t::PP, 4.0, 0x10 },
       Record { 3, 1, color_t::NB, 3.8, 0x03 },
       Record { 7, 2, color_t::O,  6.0, 0x09 },
       Record { 1, 1, color_t::NB, 3.5, 0x12 },
       Record { 2, 1, color_t::NB, 3.5, 0x14 },
       Record { 5, 2, color_t::DP, 3.5, 0x15 },
       Record { 6, 2, color_t::O,  5.0, 0x12 },
    };

    using namespace boost;

    std::cout << "Insertion order: ";
    dump(table | transformed(getId)) << "\n";

    std::cout << "byID: ";
    dump(table.get<byID>() | transformed(getId)) << "\n";

    std::cout << "Type 2: ";
    dump(
        make_iterator_range(table.get<byType>().equal_range(2))
      | transformed(getId)) << "\n";

    auto& query = table.get<byDetails>();

    std::cout << "Color == NB, Hex = [0x00..0x0f]: ";
    {
        auto lb = query.upper_bound(make_tuple(color_t::NB, 0x00));
        auto ub = query.upper_bound(make_tuple(color_t::NB, 0x0f));

        dump(make_iterator_range(lb, ub) | transformed(getId)) << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Color == NB: ";
    dump(make_iterator_range(query.equal_range(make_tuple(color_t::NB))) | transformed(getId)) << "\n";

    // adhoc order:
    {
        auto& adhoc = table.get<byCustomRandomAccess>();

        std::vector<reference_wrapper<Record const>> tmp(adhoc.begin(), adhoc.end());

        // random shuffle, e.g.:
        std::random_shuffle(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());

        // OR: use some crazy order
        auto craziness =  [](Record const& a, Record const& b) 
                { return (a.ID - 10*a.Type) < (b.ID - 10*b.Type); };

        sort(tmp, craziness);

        // optionally, reflect that order back into the `byCustomRandomAccess` index:
        adhoc.rearrange(tmp.begin());
    }

    std::cout << "Custom order persisted: ";
    dump(table.get<byCustomRandomAccess>() | transformed(getId)) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Insertion order: 4 3 7 1 2 5 6 
byID: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
Type 2: 6 5 7 
Color == NB, Hex = [0x00..0x0f]: 3 
Color == NB: 3 1 2 
Custom order persisted: 5 6 7 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Here's the live stream of me coding the example: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/table-like-datastructure-boost-multiindex/ ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: Thanks! You made it look like it was very easy ))

Comment: Cheers! Boost libraries are nice if you know how to wield them. I use them liberally for rapid prototyping. Depending on specifications/requirements I'd recommend different solutions here (Postgres, sqlite, sqlite+encryption etc.). Often, memory mapped data structures win for prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `std::tuple` with `std::vector` :

```
using sql_table_1 = std::vector<std::tuple<size_t,size_t,Color,float,size_t>>
```

in order to sort, you sort with `std::sort` + costumized comparator, for example, let's sort according to `weight`:

```
sql_table_1 table {/*...populate...*/};
using row = std::tuple<size_t,size_t,Color,float,size_t>;
std::sort(table.begin(),table.end(),[](const row& row1, const row& row2){
   return std::get<3>(row1) < std::get<3>(row2);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but while a number of columns is fixed, I need to be able to sort it by multiple columns

Comment: so give it a costumized comparator which does it.. and use std::array instead

Comment: Why a `tuple` instead of a `struct` or a `class`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think that in the loger term the code will be more generic over classes because tuples can interface with variadic templates easier and you'll have better chance to templetify parts of your code over ad-hoc classes. but I might be wrong here

Comment: @David Haim, I think it is not just about giving a costumized comparator, I may also have to develop a new sorting algorithm as I will not be able to sort it in one go.

Comment: So I think the best idea is simply use ready-to-use sql library.

Comment: I concur with @DavidHaim - even though Boost MultiIndex is good to know about :)

Answer (score 0):

The first natural way that comes to my head is to use templates + classes. Your class would hold pre-defined fields(e.g. `int ID`, `int Type`, etc.). You could overload sort function for your class with template parameters, so that you could call something like `instance.SortBy<field>()`. This would require you to create separate set of methods and fields each time you want different class, so after some time it could get pretty tedious, but for small tasks it could be sufficient. Now it's probably much easier to use existing libraries, but if I had some small task regarding the pre-defined data, I would probably go with this solution.

Comment: Yes, it does look like a tedious task now. I hoped it was a common problem with an existing solution... But suppose I cant get away with that